# GitLab unable to connect with database

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, gitlab

I am trying to use separate containers for GitLab, Redis and PostgreSQL in Kubernetes with Gluster. I am launching the three containers in the order PostgreSQL, Redis and then GitLab. First two work fine but when i try launching GitLab, it's somehow not finding the database configuration.

```
[root@cent-gluster-workstation ~]# kubectl logs gitlab-3743104516-plk3x -p
Initializing logdir...
Initializing datadir...
Installing configuration templates...
Configuring gitlab...
Configuring gitlab::database
ERROR:
  Please configure the database connection.
  Refer http://git.io/wkYhyA for more information.
  Cannot continue without a database. Aborting...
```

I confirmed that i was able to telnet from within the GitLab pod to PostgreSQL pod on port 5432.

```
root@gitlab-1182173148-t47fj:/home/git/gitlab# telnet postgresql 5432
Trying 10.42.154.36...
Connected to postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Deployment and service configuration for GitLab and PostgreSQL:

```
[root@cent-gluster-workstation ~]# cat postgresql-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: postgresql
  name: postgresql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: postgresql
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: gitlabhq_production
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: gitlab
        image: postgres:9.6.3
        name: postgresql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gluster-vol1
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
        resources: {}
      volumes:
      - name: gluster-vol1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: gluster-dyn-pvc
status: {}


[root@cent-gluster-workstation ~]# cat postgresql-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: postgresql
  name: postgresql
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: postgres
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: postgresql
status:
  loadBalancer: {}


[root@cent-gluster-workstation ~]# cat gitlab-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: gitlab
  name: gitlab
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: gitlab
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: GITLAB_PORT
          value: "80"
        - name: GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE
          value: 110Ect4ClClGBH06RSEQm4uKCxbpCyPzxfdLORkkssrStDnrQgpSSV
        - name: GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE
          value: MWxqmqqQkG1EXz9iz7Up4tEGBIEtFjxr1rL1Ry1rWCTWBjw3qxtvOM
        - name: GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE
          value: 2KOeHYHNXB4r2XDZzy3XVrH2r0t6j71MBDUmfx4FxRPqjI5KZ9j4Md
        - name: GITLAB_SSH_PORT
          value: "10022"
        image: sameersbn/gitlab:9.3.9
        name: gitlab
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gluster-vol1
          mountPath: /home/git/data
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 22
        resources: {}
      volumes:
      - name: gluster-vol1
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: gluster-dyn-pvc
status: {}
```

When i was using these three containers without Kubernetes and Gluster, i was able to get GitLab up and running by following the steps in the Quick Start section of [this](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#quick-start) link. In this case, i was using volume mount path as `/srv/docker/gitlab/` for all three containers (GitLab, Redis and PostgreSQL).

In the current case, as you can see in the deployment and service YAMLs above, i am using Gluster volume to map the container paths. Does this has anything to do with the issue or something else is wrong somewhere?

UPDATE 1: I have changed the service port name from 'headless' to 'postgres' in `postgresql-service.yaml` above. When i tried accessing database from application pod using `psql`, it's unable to connect:

```
[rancher@node-c ~]$ docker exec -it 07a05cef7378 /bin/bash
groups: cannot find name for group ID 2000
root@gitlab-1182173148-b33z2:/home/git/gitlab# psql -U postgres -h 10.42.20.99
Password for user postgres:
root@gitlab-1182173148-b33z2:/home/git/gitlab# psql -U gitlab -h 10.42.20.99
Password for user gitlab:
psql: FATAL:  database "gitlab" does not exist
```

However, if i try connecting to `psql` from within the database pod, i am able to do so.

```
[root@node-c ~]# docker exec -it 4c968c09bccf /bin/bash
root@postgresql-1124339636-4377k:/# psql -U gitlab
psql: FATAL:  database "gitlab" does not exist
root@postgresql-1124339636-4377k:/# psql -U postgres
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                      List of databases
        Name         |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
---------------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 gitlabhq_production | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 postgres            | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                     |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1           | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                     |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 gitlab    | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

One thing that i'm confused about is that on both app and db pod, when i try accessing the database, don't know why Postgres treats `gitlab` as database although i explicitly provide `-U` before it.

Comment: Do the postgres logs say anything interesting? Also, while I appreciate the telnet test, it would be more valuable to attempt to connect with an actual postgres client (psql, jdbc, pyscopg2, whatever-ruby-uses). [This GH issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/415) may interest you, too, unless you have already successfully run `initdb` in your GlusterFS mount

Comment: As a very minor aside, you can certainly call your Service port name anything you want, but "headless" means something specific in k8s Services, and may confuse others who see that name. Again: this is merely for your consideration

Comment: Thanks. Let me check connectivity using `psql` if i can install it on the app pod. For the headless thing, actually these files were generated by `kompose`. I'll change the service name. By the way, what's the order of execution: `service creation` and then `deployment` or vice-versa?

Comment: _By the way, what's the order of execution: service creation and then deployment or vice-versa?_ out of habit I usually do the Deployment first, but I think it's player's choice. The strong advantage I can imagine to Service-first is if you have other teams/containers/etc that depend upon the Dep and can tolerate nothing responding to the Service until all things are squared up

Comment: (man, I wish SO had threads) _don't know why Postgres treats gitlab as database although i explicitly provide -U before it._ because you did not specify `-d` to select a database, PG will attempt to connect to a db named the same as the user; that's likely why `psql -U postgres` worked like it did

Comment: True. Service-first will make more sense in the scenario you mentioned. You're right that db had to be specified first while running the `psql` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i tried accessing database from application pod using psql, it's unable to connect

That is actually false; it **connected** just fine, what it failed to do was **authenticate**. I would expect re-running that command as `psql --host postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local -d gitlabhq_production -U gitlab` would do what you meant.

I am presuming `10.42.20.99` is the **Pod** IP, because the second snippet shows `10.42.154.36` as the Service IP. I mention this because you are certainly welcome to use PG's Pod IP for testing, but I strongly, strongly recommend against using anything except the Service [hostname or IP], with *my* preference going to the hostname because it makes reasoning about connect strings much, much easier.

---

Having said that, based solely upon the snippet you posted, it appears the 4 `DB_` environment variable are missing from the `gitlab` Deployment descriptor, [as shown here](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L37-L42)

---

Although you didn't ask, keeping the [environment for postgres](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L18-L20) in sync with the environment for the `gitlab` Deployment is a perfect case for [Kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), combined with the [valueFrom: secretKeyRef:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#envvarsource-v1-core) mechanism. As you might suspect, also handy for storing the value of `GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE` and friends

Comment: You guessed it right. :) Thanks a lot for the 4 variables! I never suspected those would be the reason because when i set up these three containers `outside` of Kubernetes, i didn't had to declare those in my GitLab container startup script. I used `--link gitlab-postgresql:postgresql --link gitlab-redis:redisio` in my GitLab script in that case as described in the same setup under 'Quick Start'. And thanks for the Kubernetes secret things too. Keeping sensitive data outside is a must. Would have come to my mind later while `checking-in`. :)